# Polylines appear even if map is set to null (Google maps V3 Javascript API)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-maps

I've got some code to make polylines dynamically between two points. When at least two points are on array, I make the polyline between these two points visibles.

The issue is that when I remove points, at first, polylines disappear but reapper if I'm moving the map or zooming, it's super weird.

Here is the function to make all possible polylines, then i store them in travelLines

```
setTravelLines() {
      this.lieuxIndexes.forEach((lieu, index) => {
        for (let i = index; i < this.valise.length - 1; i++) {
          const points = [
            {
              lat: lieu.coordonnees[1],
              lng: lieu.coordonnees[0],
            },
            {
              lat: this.valise[i + 1].coordonnees[1],
              lng: this.valise[i + 1].coordonnees[0],
            }
          ];

          const polyline = new this.google.maps.Polyline({
              path: points,
              geodesic: true,
              strokeColor: "#60F047",
              strokeWeight: 4,
          });
          this.travelLines.push({
            polyline,
            indexes: [
              index,
              i + 1
            ]});
        }
      });
    }
```

Then the function who decide if we prompt polylines or not

```
promptPolylines(lieux) {
      if (lieux)
        this.lieuxIndexes = lieux;
      this.clearTravelLines();
      const lieuxOrganise = this.lieuxIndexes.filter((lieu) => lieu.jour > 0);
      lieuxOrganise.sort((lieuA, lieuB) => {
        return lieuA.jour - lieuB.jour
      });
      lieuxOrganise.forEach((lieu, index) => {
        if (lieuxOrganise[index + 1]) {
          const line = this.findTravelLine(lieu.id, lieuxOrganise[index + 1].id);
          line.polyline.setMap(this.map);
        }
      });
    }
```

with utils functions:

```
clearTravelLines() {
      this.travelLines.forEach((line) => {
        line.polyline.setMap(null);
      });
    }
```

```
findTravelLine(indexA, indexB) {
      return this.travelLines.filter((line) => (line.indexes[0] === indexA && line.indexes[1] === indexB)
                                                || (line.indexes[1] === indexA && line.indexes[0] === indexB))[0];
    }
```

The issue is already here with only two points

Comment: Please do not edit solutions into the question. Instead, post a proper answer below. (And, try to keep your language family-friendly; no expletives.) Thanks.

Comment: Ok, i'll make a more detailed answer to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the issue. it's directly correlated to the use of VueJS.

Indeed, I've initialized my array of polylines: `travelLines` in the `data` function of my component.

When we're doing that, we have this kind of issue where a polyline where the map is set to null still appear when you zoom in.

Instead, you'll declare and init your objects and arrays related to google maps after the API have been loaded.

It will be something like that:

```
async mounted() {
    try {
      this.google = await gmapsInit();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
    // Initialize your variables related to maps here
},
```